# JSP DateTimePicker не могу добавить

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

Помогите разобраться, почему не подключается DateTimePicker ...

в pom.xml

```
...
        <!-- Webjars (static dependencies distributed as JAR files) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-jquery.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-bootstrap.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
            <artifactId>datetimepicker</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-datetimepicker.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
...
```

в index.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title><spring:message code="app.title"/></title>
    <base href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="webjars/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="webjars/datetimepicker/2.5.14/jquery.datetimepicker.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/jquery/3.3.1-1/jquery.min.js" defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/datetimepicker/2.5.14/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js" defer></script>
</head>
<html>

<body>

<main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 pt-3 px-4">

    <label class="col-form-label" for="startDate">StartDate</label>
    <input class="form-control col-5" name="startDate" id="startDate"/>

...

</main>


</body>

<!-- Инициализация Bootstrap DateTimePicker -->
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#startDate').datepicker('show');
    });
</script>
</html>
```

А не появляется календарь, при клике мышкой и все!...
[image: не появляется календарь, при клике мышкой и все!...]

Answer (score 0):

Вы подключаете библиотеку [jQuery DateTimePicker](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/), а инициализировать пытаетесь [jQuery UI DatePicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). Правильная инициализация календаря jQuery DateTimePicker выглядит так:

```
$('#startDate').datetimepicker();
```

Comment: Это я уже столько всяких вариантов перепробовал, что не поправил, прежде чем здесь выложить. Вариант: 

`<script> $(function () { $('#startDate').datetimepicker(); }); </script> `

тоже не работает...

Comment: Тогда проверяйте в инспекторе, загрузились ли js и css файлы и нет ли ошибок в консоли, нет ли второго элемента с `id="startDate"`. Если всё в порядке, создайте [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ([вроде такого](https://jsfiddle.net/9b6f2vjw/)) и добавьте его в вопрос.